# Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)) in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I wanted to create a new solution with a new project (any project template) in VS 2019 and I faced this error:

```
Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
```

I tried:

1. Delete all settings folders for Visual Studio in `%UserProfile%` and `%AppData%`.
2. Then I uninstalled and installed it.

But nothing happened. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Sara Liu](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/sara%20liu/activity), I found a solution:

In System Properties, Advanced, Environment Variables, System variables, set PATH:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```